# Why nested functions can access variables from outer functions, but are not allowed to modify them

Tags: python, scope, python-2.x

In the 2nd case below, Python tries to look for a local variable. When it doesn't find one, why can't it look in the outer scope like it does for the 1st case?

This looks for x in the local scope, then outer scope:

```
def f1():
    x = 5
    def f2():
         print x
```

This gives `local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` error:

```
def f1():
    x = 5
    def f2():
        x+=1
```

I am not allowed to modify the signature of function f2() so I can not pass and return values of x. However, I do need a way to modify x. Is there a way to explicitly tell Python to look for a variable name in the outer scope (something similar to the `global` keyword)?

Python version: 2.7

Comment: python 3 provides `nonlocal` for this purpose, but I think it's worth asking why you need to do this.  This is a little safer than using `global`, but still doesn't feel right.

Comment: @mgilson there are many good reasons to do this, see e.g. the rationale section in pep-3104.

Comment: what version of python do you use?

Comment: @soulcheck I use Python 2.7, edited that in my question.

Comment: @Dhara sorry, don't know why the comment got posted. It was fairly obvious that you're on 2.7.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
def f1():
    x = { 'value': 5 }
    def f2():
        x['value'] += 1
```

Workaround is to use a mutable object and update members of that object. Name binding is tricky in Python, sometimes.

Comment: This works, although I ended up using a list with a single element instead of a dictionary. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is more correct to use `nonlocal` or `global`

Comment: Global is not a good idea as it will pollute the global namespace. Nonlocal is a python 3 feature, and this question specified python 2.7.

Comment: *global* doesn't work in py2.7 for question purpose, however `x['value']` is harder to write on parent scope than just `value`, so consider passing value to nested function, and then just returning `value` from nested scope to parent scope

Answer (score 194):

In Python 3.x this is possible:

```
def f1():
        x = 5
        def f2():
                nonlocal x
                x+=1
        return f2
```

The problem and a solution to it, for Python 2.x as well, are given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7535919/589206) post. Additionally, please read [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) for more information on this subject.

Comment: I just looked this up.  `nonlocal` is the statement to use here.

Comment: @user1320237 global does not work instead of nonlocal -- that was precisely my question!