# How can I get access to this nonglobal variable in nested functions in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to find a solution and have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987358/why-nested-functions-can-access-variables-from-outer-functions-but-are-not-allo) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935966/python-overwriting-variables-in-nested-functions).

Here is my code:

```
def sshRunCommand(self, command, print_stdout=True, print_stderr=True):

    def run_exec_command_thread(command):
        (stdin, stdout, stderr) = self.client.exec_command(command)

    # Appends command to always change to the home directory first
    x = "cd /home/" + self.username + "/; " + command

    # Locally output an terminal-esque command look-a-like
    if print_stdout:
        print self.username + "@" + self.payloadd + ":" + x

        exec_command_thread = Thread(
            target=run_exec_command_thread,
            args=(x,))
        exec_command_thread.daemon = True
        exec_command_thread.start()

        while exec_command_thread.isAlive():
            a = stdout.readlines()
            for b in a:
                print b
```

I want to make `stdin`, `stdout`, & `stderr` in the nested function `run_exec_command_thread` to be shared with it's parent function.  I'm using Python 2.7 so I can't use `nonlocal`.  I don't know how to share the variables between them for this specific case because I don't know how to implement a dict solution in this case because the object type is a `paramiko.channel.ChannelFile`.  I'm hoping somebody can get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really related to nested functions.

It looks like `stdin` etc won't be created until the function is run, i.e. in a new `Thread`.

This means it should be solvable using a standard **variable sharing across Threads** approach, e.g. using a `Queue` - see here: [How to share a variable between 2 threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461413/)

Comment: So I'm using Queues already for sharing data between threads, but that exec_command runs and populates a local variable called stdout.  I want to get that output in real time because the command takes over 15 minutes to finish (so I don't want to print after it completes).  So a solution to this is going to require running the exec_command in a separate thread and consistently read the variable.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?