# How to make inner functions see variables of enclosing function?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read/Write Python Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009402/read-write-python-closures)

In the following function, the internal function does not modify the argument but just modifies the copy.

```
def func():
  i = 3
  def inc(i):
    i = i + 3
  print i
  inc(i)
  inc(i)
  print i

func()
```

Is it possible to avoid repeated code and put that inside a function in python? I tried the following too but it throws error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment`

```
def func():
  i = 3
  def inc():
    i = i + 3
  print i
  inc()
  inc()
  print i

func()
```

Comment: It is one of my favorite interview questions. I suggest you read about variable visibility in Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/Write Python Closures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2009402/395760)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8447947/331473

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3 you'd do this:

```
def func():
  i = 3
  def inc():
    nonlocal i
    i = i+3
  print(i)
  inc()
  inc()
  print(i)

func()
```

In python 2.x using `global` doesn't work because the variable is in an outer scope, but it's not global. Hence, you'll need to pass the variable as an argument.

This is the problem that [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) addresses.

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
def func():
    i = 3
    def inc(i):
        return i + 3
    print i
    i = inc(i)
    i = inc(i)
    print i

func()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 you can use `nonlocal`.

```
>>> def func():
    i = 3
    def inc():
        nonlocal i
        i += 3
    print(i)
    inc()
    inc()
    print(i)

>>> func()
3
9
>>>
```