# Python - Memoization with Decorators - dict vs scalar - understandin nonlocal mem

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, difference, scalar

I try to understand memorization, particularly regarding **nonlocal mem** with the code below:

```
def mem_last(f):
    mem = 0
    def helper(x):
        print("mem = ", mem)
        mem = f(x + mem)
        return mem
    return helper

def mem_last1(f):
    mem = {"0": 0}
    def helper(x):
        print("mem = ", mem)
        mem["0"] = f(x + mem["0"])
        return mem["0"]
    return helper
    
def f(x):
    print("x = ", x)
    return x

f = mem_last(f) 
#f = mem_last1(f)

print(f(0))
```

When I use f = mem_last(f), where mem is a scalar, there is an error:

```
py mem.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mem.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(f(0))
  File "mem.py", line 4, in helper
    print("mem = ", mem)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mem' referenced before assignment
```

If I use `f = mem_last1(f)`, where `mem` is a dict, there is no error and it works well.

Please explain why there is a difference between a dict and a scalar var.
Thank you very much.

PS: I am using 3.7.7 64 bit on Windows 10.
I have read the thread you provide and I fix it by add a line "nonlocal mem" before 'print("mem = ", mem)'.

However, my question is why I **do not need to add line "nonlocal mem"** when mem is a **dict or a list**, and **no error** occur. So why python treats scalar different from dict or list?

Comment: Your issue is `mem = f(x + mem)` line which redefines `mem` as a local variable. Python is a dynamic language.

Comment: There are several questions on SO with some great answers explaining this behaviour and proposing some workarounds. The most complete is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2009402/6682517) IMHO (both the question and the accepted answer).

Comment: Thank you very much. The error is at line: print("mem = ", mem). I fix it by add a line "nonlocal mem" before this line. However, my question is why I do not need to add line "nonlocal mem" when mem is a dict or a list.

Comment: because you're not _reassigning_ the name the dict/list points to, you're simply mutating it in place.